# Why does the Rust compiler allow index out of bounds?

Tags: rust

Can someone explain why this compiles:

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3];
    println!("{:?}", a[4]);
}
```

When running it, I got:

> thread '' panicked at 'index out of bounds: the len is 3 but the index is 4', ../src/libcollections/vec.rs:1132

Comment: Probably the same reason that it doesn't throw a compiler error in any other language; the compiler sees `4` as just an expression, which may as well be `f(x)` that may return some other value.

Comment: Yeah but compiler has to see the expression is a constant literal, so that could be checked during compilation.

Comment: It could be added in the future or as a plugin, but it's an optimization that requires some evaluation at compile time to know how long is the vector and a pass to check calls to many methods that retrieve elements.

Comment: I would guess that the compiler simply does not know what a `Vec<int>` is and that if you start with `Vec::new()` that it's size is 0 and that if you call push on it three times, its size goes to 3 and that the index in the square bracket has to be less than the vector's size. `Vec` is just a library type. The compiler has no special knowledge about it.

Comment: There's a difference between a compile-time error, and a program that you can easily prove will crash at run-time. Your program should correctly panic only at run-time, that is what the lines of code you wrote, tell it to do. Maybe someone can add a lint to the compiler to warn you when do this, but like there's really no purpose and people working on the compiler can better spend their time elsewhere.

Comment: I'll point out that this *does* fail to compile if `a` is an array. `let a = [1, 2, 3];` results in [*"this operation will panic at runtime"*](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=11923d41d8565e499f2870fd40ee1222).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In order to understand the issue, you have to think about it in terms of what the compiler sees.

Typically, a compiler never reasons about the *value* of an expression, only about its *type*. Thus:

- `a` is of type `Vec<i32>`
- `4` is of an unknown integral type
- `Vec<i32>` implements subscripting, so `a[4]` type checks

Having a compiler reasoning about *values* is not unknown, and there are various ways to get it.

- you can allow evaluation of some expression at compile-time: `const` functions and variables.
- you can encode value into types: `const` generic parameters.
- you can use *dependent typing* which bridges the gap between types and values

Rust supports the first two since 1.51, and they could be used to get compile-time checked indexing of compile-time indexes in collections of compile-time defined length... But that would require a different interface than the `Index` trait, something like `a.at::<4>()` for example.

Thus, with `Index`, the values are checked at runtime, and the implementation of `Vec` correctly bails out (here failing).

Comment: llvm, rustc's optimizing compiler backend, does however see through these layers of abstraction when it gets down to optimizing the code. So we can see that it does statically compile it down to a failing bounds check in this particular case.

Comment: Is this answer outdated? It's been more than 6 years since the last edit.

Comment: @nbro: Not to the best of my knowledge. Some facts just are.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Rust has support for "const" keyword in function and creating `const` variables for some time now. It also supports having `struct S<const A: usize>();` now.

Answer (score 30):

If you would like to access elements of the `Vec` with index checking, you can use the `Vec` [as a slice](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.as_slice) and then use its [`get` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.get). For example, consider the following code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = vec![1, 2, 3];
    println!("{:?}", a.get(2));
    println!("{:?}", a.get(4));
}
```

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=1db90a7b7afd191688aef6c2285c996f)

This outputs:

```
Some(3)
None
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was asked here.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the following **is** a compile time error:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = [1, 2, 3];
    println!("{:?}", a[4]);
}
```

```
error: this operation will panic at runtime
 --> src/main.rs:3:22
  |
3 |     println!("{:?}", a[4]);
  |                      ^^^^ index out of bounds: the length is 3 but the index is 4
  |
  = note: `#[deny(unconditional_panic)]` on by default
```

This works because without the `vec!`, the type is `[i32; 3]`, which does actually carry length information.

With the `vec!`, it's now of type `Vec<i32>`, which no longer carries length information. Its length is only known at runtime.

Comment: Note this is only a lint, not a hard error.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but it gets raised as an error by default.